# Change Output type based on Input value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a selector component.

The selector take a value that can be either a string/number etc... or an array of string/number etc..

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gjbpvw?file=src/app/app.component.html

```
export class SelectComponent<T> implements OnInit {
  @Input() value: T | T[]
  @Input() multiple: boolean;

  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<T | T[]>() 
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I would like to use all strict check types, but I face a problem with this input.

```
<app-select [(value)]="test"></app-select>
<app-select [multiple]="true" [(value)]="test2"></app-select>

export class AppComponent  {
  test = "";
  test2: string[] = []
}
```

The above will complain about

> type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I wonder if there is a way *without* remove the strict check and *without* making 2 components, to change the Output value based on `multiple`

If `multiple = true` output will always be an array
If `multiple = false` output will never be an array

Is there a way ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried one thing and it seems to work :

*select.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css']
})
export class SelectComponent<T, U extends boolean, V = U extends true ? T extends any[] ? T : T[] : T extends (infer Tt)[] ? Tt : T> implements OnInit {
  @Input() value: V;
  @Input() multiple: U;

  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<V>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

So I had the type `U` and `V` in your component. `U` is only a boolean and type the input `multiple`.

`V` check if `U` is `true`. If yes check if `T` is an array as it should be. If it's the case, `V` is equal to `T` else `V` is equal to `T[]`. If `U` is `false`, check if `T` is an array. If true so get the type of element without the array and assign it to `V`, else `V` = `T`.

Comment: That is a good answer in theory, but angular will not complain if you use `[multiple]="false"` along with an array value

Comment: Yes, it's just to pass the errors and like this he can continue to work. And I don't remember but maybe if he generate the component with a factory the types will work good

Comment: THanks, I will try to play with this. there is some issue when some method use V, when giving for exemple an array to that method, it will say that V is not all the time an array, so will still throw an error. which is correct indeed, but not working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The Angular complaint is justified :) - but you should realize that it is complaining about the output not the input to the component.

It is complaining that the `EventEmitter<T | T[]>` can emit a type that is incompatible with the type of the input variable.

If you change the declaration of `test` and `test2` to the following, it will work:

```js
test: string | string[] = "";
test2: string | string[] = [];
```

Comment: I know the complain is justified, the thing is, in the code I am sure of the value emitted. if multiple is trye, emitter will be [] and if not just not an array. The compiler is working good, but I wonder of a way where the value emitter type is dependent of the `multiple` variable

Comment: I've been messing around with stackblitz following the same path as @KenLa answer above. Angular never complains.

Comment: then I guess making to component will not be DRY but the type will be easy to manage

Comment: Don't give up :) maybe I just haven't found the right way, follow it up with @KenLa above - he knows what he's doing